# Any way to use task schedule to boot up a computer with a keyboard trigger?

Tags: windows-10, laptop, keyboard-shortcuts, windows-task-scheduler, wireless-keyboard

**Question Restated:**
Can we use the task scheduler and in some way create a trigger (trigger = tapping a key combination on an external keyboard) for the task (task = boot up computer when lid is closed)?

**My Set-up and Context for the Issue:**
I have a Microsoft Natural Wireless Ergonomic Keyboard 7000 as well as the mouse connected to my laptop via a wireless USB to my laptop. The laptop remains closed because I connected it to my monitor. I usually have to open the computer and press the power button, wait to login before closing the lid. I'm trying to fix this problem, even though it's more of a convenience issue, really to just learn about solving these kind of problems. I'm just started a computer science degree.

**What I've tried:**
I couldn't find any search results that were useful.

I was trying to use Intellitype Pro (64-bit) to reprogram some key on the keyboard to power on my laptop even when it is closed. I had no idea how to use that program, and I figured that the computer would need to be on before I could create any keyboard shortcuts or triggers... which doesn't help when I'm trying to remote boot up the computer when the device is closed.

I was thinking that if I were to use task scheduler to boot up the computer automatically even when the lid is closed at a certain time everyday, the computer would automatically go to sleep and then I would be able to wake the computer up with the external keyboard or mouse. The problem with this is that I do not know how to use the task scheduler program, I just found out about it from some web searches and tutorials online are not extensive enough.

I'm not very familiar with these applications so detailed instructions would be very appreciated if there is a solution.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Task Scheduler to turn OFF your computer, but it won't be able to turn it on. Your computer needs to be on for the task scheduler service to execute tasks.

Here are a few other possible solutions:

### Sleep or Hibernate

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/13770/windows-shut-down-sleep-hibernate-your-pc

Both of these are low-power states you can use instead of shutting down completely. Hibernate will use very little power, and sleep will use slightly more. If you do this instead of shutting down, you should be able to wake your computer by pressing buttons on your keyboard.

---

### Wake-on-LAN

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wake-on-LAN

Wake-on-LAN is a technology standard that allows a computer on a network to be "woken", i.e. powered on, via a special signal (called a magic packet) from another device on the network.

An easy program that you can use for this is NirSoft's [WakeMeOnLan](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/wake_on_lan.html):

> This utility allows you to easily turn on one or more computers
>   remotely by sending Wake-on-LAN (WOL) packet to the remote computers. 
>   When your computers are turned on, WakeMeOnLan allows you to scan your
>   network, and collect the MAC addresses of all your computers, and save
>   the computers list into a file. Later, when your computers are turned
>   off or in standby mode, you can use the stored computers list to
>   easily choose the computer you want to turn on, and then turn on all
>   these computers with a single click.

You can also use an app on your smartphone, assuming it is on the same network, to send WOL magic packets. For example:

Android: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=co.uk.mrwebb.wakeonlan&hl=en

iOS: https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/mocha-wol/id422625778?mt=8

Answer (score -1):

I use the BIOS settings to wake the PC at a specific time each day.
The details of how to do that are manufacturer specific.
On my Dell the following changes have been made to wake it at 7:30am each day.
AutoOn=Everyday, AutoOnHr=7, AutoOnMn=30
To shut it down at 6:00pm, I use a scheduled task.
To create the task open an Admin CMD prompt and type the following:
schtasks /create /tn "DailyShutdown" /tr "shutdown -s -t 300" /SC DAILY /ST 18:00 /RU "NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM" /F